# Optimizing RabbitMQ consumers to consume in batch

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp, node-amqplib

I have an application where on every message consumption I need to query the MySQL database for some information and based on that process the consumed message. I would want to optimize this so as to prevent multiple queries on the database adding up to the load.

I was thinking of an approach where I wait for atleast **x messages** or **y seconds**. This way I can batch consume some messages and even if at some point I receive less messages, they get consumed as well.

Example: Let's say **x = 100**, **y = 10 seconds**

This means I wait for atleast 100 messages or 10 seconds whichever is first. This way I can query the database at once for 100 messagess in a single query. Also, if I get less than 100 messages, the remaining messages would be processed in a maximum 10 second window.

I am using NodeJS with the `amqplib` for consumption. I have the following code based on RabbitMQ examples:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: true});
  });
});
```

I was thinking of having a global object and add to that in every `consume` callback and check the count of that object when it reaches the **x messages** those get processed. Still, not sure how to add a upper time limit of **y seconds** on this and also ensure that if I get less than **x messages** within the time window, those get processed

Answer (score 0):

The following code would call a function after every received message, which aggregates the received messages in an array. When it is called without a message (with argument `null`) or when it sees that the message count has reached `x`, it sends the aggregated messages to a database function. Otherwise, it simply adds the message to the array (in the second part of the `if` statement).

The argument `null` is passed to the aggregate function by a timer which fires after `y` seconds. This timer is first set when the message queue has just been initialized, and gets reset whenever the aggregator sends messages into the database.

```
var messageStore = [];
var timer;

sendToDatabase = function(messages) {...}

aggregate = function(msg) {
    if (msg == null || messageStore.push(msg) == x) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(aggregate, 1000*y, null);
        sendToDatabase(messageStore);
        messageStore = [];
    }
}

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
    timer = setTimeout(aggregate, 1000*y, null);
    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
      aggregate(msg);
    }, {noAck: true});
  });
});
```

Note: I haven't been able to test this as I don't have a messaging system at hand.

Comment: this doesn't seem like a good approach because you are holding it in the global memory.  and until every message is saved to DB and you acknowledge the message, no more messages are consumed blocking the IO. This makes the whole flow very slow.